# nginx append query parameter to a react application

Tags: nginx, rewrite, querystring

I am a beginner in Nginx and I want to append a query parameter to the URL (for instance myid) in order to serve a react application. I am using nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

There are similar questions like:

[Appending query parameters to specific URI](https://serverfault.com/questions/1094994/appending-query-parameters-to-specific-uri)

But I cannot find a solution to the problem.

React usually creates static content, so using a "try_files" element (pointing to /index.html) seems logical.

Here is the configuration file

```
server {
  listen 9999 ssl default_server;
  listen [::]:9999 ssl default_server;

  ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    
  ssl_certificate        /keystores/mycert.crt.pem;         ## 
  ssl_certificate_key    /keystores/mycert.key.pem;         ## 
  ssl_client_certificate /keystores/.npm.certs.pem;         ## CA Bundle
  ssl_verify_client on;

  root /home/edu/my-react-app;

  index index.html;

  server_name _;
  error_log /home/edu/log/nginx_log debug;

  #Append query param (trying different flags)
  rewrite ^(/login)$ $1?myid=LAST last;
  #rewrite ^(/login)$ $1?myid=NO_FLAG ;
  #rewrite ^(/login)$ $1?myid=BREAK break;
  #rewrite ^(/login)$ $1?myid=REDIRECT redirect;
  #rewrite ^(/login)$ $1?myid=PERMANENT permanent;


  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/  /index.html =404; # Redirect to index.html of the "static" react application!!!
  }
}
```

I have tried all 5 flag rewrite options with these results:

**no-flag, last, and break flags**: In the log file, it states that a query parameter has been added to the URL but the new URL does not appear in the browser address bar, and the application cannot find this query param.

**redirect and permanent flags**:  In the log file, it states that the query parameter has been added to the URL MANY TIMES and the new URL appears (with the query parameter repeated many times) in the browser address bar, but the browser complains as it has been redirected many times.

Putting the "rewrite" statement into the "location" statement doesn't work.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want *React* to see the query parameter you will need to use `redirect` or `permanent`. The other modes of `rewrite` are internal to Nginx. See [the `rewrite` documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite).

To protect against a redirection loop, you will need to wrap the `rewrite...redirect` within an `if` block. For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
location = /login {
    if ($arg_myid = "") {
        rewrite ^ /login?myid=xxx redirect;
    }
    try_files /index.html =404;
}
```

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if` within a `location` block.

Comment: Thank you very much! You have hit the nail on the head! I have wasted a whole week trying to find a solution. I wanted to read information from the client certificate and pass it to the react app to fill the menu with the authorized options.